# undefined method `render' for class `ActionView::Base'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, render, actionview, alias-method

When I start the application crashes following error

```
/home/stereodenis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@nyanya/gems/haml-3.1.6/lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:15:in `alias_method': undefined method `render' for class `ActionView::Base' (NameError)
```

What maybe wrong?

full trace https://gist.github.com/5e3244d488068c9d0ba7

Comment: Have a look here: http://markmail.org/message/hrbuapu5wsqtaq3k#query:+page:1+mid:q6pyzncm3qzrzhu5+state:results

Comment: sorry, but I found nothing helpful for me in this message

Comment: I reinstall my gemset and application starts with no errors!
I don't know why but it works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using a render inside a helper you have to include the functionality!

```
include AbstractController::Rendering
```

Hope it helps