# How to use multiple renderizations inside a helper or presenter as if in a view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my helper module.

```
module MyHelper

  def render_partials collection
    collection.each do |object|
      render partial: "...", object: @object = object
    end
  end

end
```

It's raising an error: `` undefined method `render' for #<... ``. What i should include to work?

Comment: Have you tried `view_context.render`?

Comment: @max yes, i pass it to presenter constructor by controller and works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include

```
include AbstractController::Rendering
```

Referring to [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816118/undefined-method-render-for-class-actionviewbase)

Comment: But i would like to use render method inside a enumerator method, but in controller context that doesn't possible because the Rails raise an exception in multiples renderization case.

Comment: Modify you Question please if so, Answer is working for your question case

Comment: Sure. Sorry. I had not slept at that time. The question has been modified.